# Color problem for code in Latex

Tags: color, code

I'm trying to insert a python code in my latex document so, I used a couple of colors to highlight the keywords and string words ...

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,blue,rgb,]{tubsbook}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{array,multirow}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[activate]{pdfcprot}

\definecolor{codegreen}{rgb}{0,0.6,0}
\definecolor{codegray}{rgb}{0.5,0.5,0.5}
\definecolor{backcolour}{rgb}{0.95,0.95,0.92}
\lstdefinestyle{mystyle}{
  backgroundcolor=\color{backcolour},   
  commentstyle=\color{codegreen},
  keywordstyle=\color{Maroon},
  numberstyle=\tiny\color{codegray},
  stringstyle=\color{magenta},
  basicstyle=\footnotesize,
  breakatwhitespace=false,         
  breaklines=true,                 
  captionpos=b,                    
  keepspaces=true,                 
  numbers=left,                    
  numbersep=5pt,                  
  showspaces=false,                
  showstringspaces=false,
  showtabs=false,                  
  tabsize=2
}
```

But I'm getting this error with the maroon color : **! Package xcolor Error: Undefined color `Maroon'**
What could be the reason?

Comment: Load  `xcolor` with option `[dvipsnames]` or `[svgnames]` (more colours).

Comment: i tried with options but i get this : **! LaTeX Error: Option clash for package xcolor.**

Comment: This means `xcolor` is already loaded by some other package (hyperref?) with other options or no option. In this case, either use `\PassOptionsToPackage{svgnames or dvipsnames or both}{xcolor}`, or write the option in the document class options.

Comment: @Bernard: I suspect, the class `tubsbook` loads `xcolor` already, but I can't tesst this

Comment: @Christian Hupfer/ Yes, I'v just checked: hyperref only loads `color`, `hycolor` and `xcolor-patch`, none of which seem to load `xcolor`. That said, I think the advice is valid for any (normal?) class.

Comment: @Bernard The class `tubsbook` (at least the version I've found) loads `xcolor`. At least twice. Quite messy, I'd say.

Comment: @Bernard: `\PassOptionsToClass` should work unless the class screws the option handling up ;-)

Comment: If the class loads `xcolor` then try `\RequirePackage[options]{xcolor}` before `\documentclass`, where `options` are those mentioned in other comments

Comment: @ChristianHupfer added where?

Comment: @daleif: Sorry, I meant `\PassOptionsToPackage` of course

Comment: @campa: Where did you find the class?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer but again where do you place that, before `\documentclass`? I've never need it used out side packages or classes

Comment: @daleif: Hm, I should test it, most likely. -- option handling is sometimes a little bit awkward

Comment: @ChristianHupfer it does work, when added before `\documentclass` (of course did not test it for a package that was loaded by a class, but it nicely added the option to `xolor` loaded in the preamble without options)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer LaTeX-Vorlagen im Corporate Design der TU Braunschweig ([external link](http://tubslatex.ejoerns.de/)).

Comment: @campa: Oh damn (and quite embarassing): a German University has such a messy 'template' . Thanks!